# Not able to retain Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-fragmentactivity

I've a Fragment where I want to pick a picture from Gallery and update it in it's ImageView. I'm able to do so like this:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
        var uri = data!!.data
        setImageBitmap(uri)
    }
}
```

After image is updated in ImageView, Fragment gets destroyed and returns to Main/Hosting Activity. I want to stay in Fragment to continue working in it. How can I control when to return to it's hosting activity ?

Comment: fragment should not get destroyed for no reason, are you sure you don't have any code in Activity onCreate/onResume that would destroy/replace it?

Comment: @Pawel: Thanks for pointing out the issue. I was refreshing in onResume() :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It was the refresh code in Activity's `onResume()` lifecycle method that was causing fragment to close right away.